# What is wrong with MyBufferedInputStream?

Tags: java, android, file

I need to process file line by line and want to know offsets of start of lines.
Because there is no readLine in BufferedInputStream, I coded my own readLine.
It works fine except offset. When file length becomes long, offset returns incorrect value.
What is wrong with my code?

```
class MyBufferedInputStream extends BufferedInputStream {
    long offset = 0;

    public MyBufferedInputStream(InputStream in) {
        super(in);
    }

    public String readLine() throws IOException {
        int b, i = 0;
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];

        while (true) {
            b = read();
            offset++;
            if (b == -1)
                return null;
            else if (b == '\n') 
                return (new String(buf));
            else // assume line in not longer than 256
                buf[i++] = (byte) b;
        }
    }

    public long getOffset() {
        return offset;
    }

    public void resetOffset() {
        offset = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `BufferedReader` has a `readLine()` - I would suggest you use that.

Comment: Why didn't you use BufferedReader? http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: I know. Isn't it slower than BufferedInputStream?

Comment: @user1301568 - always favor using standard libraries over re-inventing the wheel!

Comment: why reinvent DataInputStream.readLine ?

Comment: @BufferedReader advocates, it reads characters, not bytes, which implies a knowledge of the encoding, which may not be the case. However, the use of new String() without encoding contradicts that. (and is very dangerous)

Comment: @njzk2 - reading ***lines*** already implies a byte conversion to characters. Fuzzy source encoding is another problem entirely.

Comment: @Perception : agreed (and don't like all this readLine() notion anyway. too fuzzy), but in this case, a single byte could be considered as a separator with a conversion that, under most circumstances can be considered **almost** universal. And as I said, user1301568 uses new String(byte[]) afterward anyway, so yes, there is a byte conversion.

Comment: I reinvented to get offset of each line. It seemed to be hard with BufferedReader. Do you know better solution than mine?

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush when you read data and at the end close the buffer, some data could still in memory generating you conflicts and that's why it doesn't run appropiately and you see the results sometimes and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

As Pescis suggests in a comment, you should use `BufferedReader` to read lines of text rather than extending `BufferedInputStream` and adding your own `readLine()` method.

Java has two kinds of classes for I/O: streams, and readers / writers.

**Streams** (`java.io.InputStream`, `java.io.OutputStream` and everything that extends them) are for reading binary data (bytes).

**Readers** and **writers** (`java.io.Reader` and `java.io.Writer`) are for reading and writing text; they contain logic to translate characters from and to bytes, using a character encoding.

Note that in your code, you are using `new String(buf)` to convert a buffer containing bytes to a string. Since you are not specifying a character encoding, the default character encoding of the system will be used, which is not always what you want.

Example of using a `BufferedReader`:

```
InputStream in = ...;  // Wherever you get an InputStream from

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

br.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. if line is longer than your 256 byte buffer then you'll get an overflow
2. Last line will not be returned (returns null), if it doesn't end with newline
3. If you find a `\n` after going through 10 bytes, then you'll return a new String of 256 length where first 10 characters are your line and 246 characters `\0`. In other words, you always return strings of 256 characters for each line, regardless of how long the line is.

What is your reason for not using `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))`, and then calling `readLine` on buffered  reader?

Comment: I want to know offsets of start of lines. Is there anyway to know offset using BufferedReader?

Comment: No. However, not using a reader (i.e. implementing this on top of a Stream) means you're working with bytes rather than characters, which means you have to provide your own logic for encodings. You should implement your own BufferedReader rather than your own BufferedInputStream. And in case you do so, you should pay attention to the mistakes I noted above.